# Django How do you pass a field attribute after the __init__ function

Tags: django

i would like to pass this:

```
 client_satisfaction = forms.DecimalField(widget=forms.NumberInput(
        attrs={
            'type':'range',
            'class':'form-control-range',
            'step': '1',
            'min': '1',
            'max': variable}), 
        label='Client Satisfaction',        
        required=False)
```

After this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    pk_num_project = User.objects.filter(pk = user.id)
    company_objective = CompanyObjectives.objects.get(user_rel_objectives=user.id)        
    super(ProcessForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Currently, in my forms I have the first client_satisfaction then I do def **init**  how can inverse this. I want to do this because I am running a query that is finding the results and putting it into a variable. so I need to run the query first and then put it into my variable. Any ideas, I am new to Django so it it makes little sense plz let me know or point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to pass any field after init function for that in the init you have to put specify init's super first after that you can pass whatever you want

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):     
        super(ProcessForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # this all code is after the init initialized code
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        pk_num_project = User.objects.filter(pk = user.id)
        company_objective = CompanyObjectives.objects.get(user_rel_objectives=user.id)
```